# Конвертация даты в sql запросе

Tags: запрос, sql

Всем привет, скажите у меня в ячейке есть такое значение:

```
1356364843
```

Это Unix-Дата, так вот а мне надо превратить её в вид:

```
24.12.2012
```

Т.к мне нужно сделать сравнение сразу в запросе, и если дата равна той что укажет пользователь... однако я не знаю как её сразу преобразовать в такой вид...Запрос примерно такой:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tb_user WHERE конвертация(date_reg) = '$date_enter'
```

Где конвертация, это название функции с помощью которой можно это сделать(не знаю как она называется), где $date_enter - это переменная в которой хранятся данные введённые пользователем.

Comment: т.е. вы предлагаете серверу БД взять каждую строку таблицы и преобразовать значение из одного полей к определенному виду и сравнить со значением, котроое вам лень преобразовать к формату, хранящемуся в базе? подумайте над вопросом еще раз, может быть решение придет само...

ЗЫ только не надо рассказывать, что в таблице тб_юзер всего две записи, впоследствии такие запросы переносят и на таблицы с миллионами строк и удивляются тормозам майэскуэль.

Comment: А какой запрос тогда лучше?

Comment: Я думаю, что @Yura Ivanov? тонко намекает вам, что проще преобразовать в TIMESTAMP дату, которую вы собираетесь использовать в условии запроса ))

Comment: Не забудьте при таком преобразовании сравнивать диапазон. т.е.
date_reg<$formated_date_input<date_reg+sec_per_day

Answer (score 3):

Для MySQL делается так

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tb_user WHERE date_reg = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$date_enter')
```

Обратите внимание, что конвертируется не значение в БД, а входной параметр. Это гораздо эффективнее с точки зрения производительности, т.к. конвертацию нужно выполнить всего один раз, а не для каждой записи таблицы. Кроме того, если поле `date_reg` проиндексировано, то в таком варианте еще и будет использоваться индекс